# FFmpeg zoom not smooth-centered (but zigzag)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, zooming

I try to perform a basic [zoompan](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#zoompan) with **FFmpeg**. I have an input image (.png 1280x720) and i create an 8 seconds video (.mp4 320x180) from it, with a zoom. This is my command:

> ffmpeg -loop 1 -i in_img.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict experimental -framerate 25 **-vf zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.011835363,2.1835363)':d=375:x=400:y=247** -s 320x180 -t 00:00:08.882 out_vid.mp4

Everything works...but the zoom is not looking okay. It is going zig-zag.

Does anyone know how to make it zoom smooth, like centered? (And not first left then right)

Thanks

### EDIT

---

I've come a small step closer to a solution by slightly modifying the 'x' and 'y' in the -vf filter (rest of the command is the same as above):

> -vf
>   zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.022,3.25)':d=375:x='if(gte(zoom,3.25),x,x+8.24)':y='if(gte(zoom,3.25),y,y+4.72)':s=1280x720

I incement **x** and **y** every frame *(for x +8.24, for y +4.72, i know those values because i know how many frames it takes get to the end-zoom state)* so that it will move to its end zoom state coordinate (1011,582), see image:

[image: Zoom Visualization]
[This is the video of the result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aF-My9FDLD0), as you can see it does not do the zig-zag effect, but now it looks like its going first to the center and then to the zoomed result. Or is that only an illusion??
Any idea's?

Comment: Try it without rescaling and check.

Comment: Same result, [watch here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3NH4cAvca8).. But maybe it's because the x and y I use are the top-left coordinates of the zoom end position, [see this visualization](https://i.gyazo.com/96784bb4085e293ac93ee22da3ca583d.png). 
Is that correct reasoning or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zoom from zoom level `1` (1280x720) to zoom level `5` (256x144) and pan to bottom right, with final position (1011,568) in 125 frames, and output video as 320x180, use

```
-vf zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0320,5)':d=125:x='(iw-(iw/zoom))*(1011/1024)': \
                                         y='(ih-(ih/zoom))*(568/576)',scale=320x180
```

where `0.0320` is division of `(final zoom - initial zoom) / frames to zoom in`, `1024` is `input width - final width` and `576` is `input height - final height`

FFmpeg doesn't seem to smooth out the interpolation, so fine zoom and pans will be jittery.

Comment: What it means input width - final width = 1024? If I have input 1717 and final 3600, I get -1883. It works backwards than I want and stretches whole picture ratio to my initial dimensions instead keeping the zoom dimensions

Comment: My starting position: 983,1244; starting size: 1717x1080
ending position: 0,725; ending size: 3600x2265. Whole image 3600x3600. How to apply into your code?